# Google cloud HTTP Load balancing automatic rate limit

Tags: server, load-balancing, google-cloud-platform

I have the following setup:

1. One server serving a php page which caps at 1500 RPS when load testing from another machine in the same data center.
2. An HTTP load balancer with this server as the only backend, which caps at 30 requests per second. I have also tried adding other identical backend servers to the load balancer, and end up with the same 30 RPS limit on the total number of requests.

Is this behaviour due to the load balancer trying to stop a potential DOS attack because all the load is being generated from a single IP? If so, how do I disable it?

Comment: GCE load balancing has a 'Balancing mode' configuration which you configure for either max CPU utilization or max request rate to the underlying backends. How is your LB configured?

Comment: I have tried doing it with both. Also tried varying the capacity field, doesn't work. I also tried starting clusters in different data centers and generating load. Still caps at 30 rps.